# How to test a private asynchronous function

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I have a `MessageHandler` that has:

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Message e) {
       if (e.Type == speed ){
                var action = new Action (async ()=> await ProcessMessage(containerId, msgType, bytes).ConfigureAwait(false));
                action.BeginInvoke(action.EndInvoke, null);
       }
}
```

where `ProcessMessage` is

```
 private async Task ProcessMessage(string containerId, MessageType messageType, byte[] data)
        {
            switch (messageType)
            {
                case MessageType.Fast:
                    await HandleFast(containerId, data);
                    break;
                case MessageType.Slow:
                    await HandleSlow(containerId, data);
                    break;
                case MessageType.Continuous:
                    await HandleContinuous(containerId, data);
                    break;
                case MessageType.Unknown:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(messageType));
            }
        }
```

.
Each `HandleXYZ` is along the lines of:

```
private async Task HandleFast(string containerId, byte[] data)
        {
            if (!TryDeserializeObject(data, out Message msg)
            {
                return;
            }
            await _dataAccess.UpsertFastAsync(containerId, tenantId, msg);
        }
```

I want to test if the right `UpsertXYZ` is invoked given the messageType. What I have tried is:

1. Shim on the `MessageHandler` - with a flag in the shim that updates if the right function is invoked. Unfortunately can't test which function was invoked because all async behavior I want to test is under that `OnNewMessageReceived` layer, and I can't call `await` on a synchronous function.
2. Mut.PrivateObject MessageHandler- to call ProcessMessage by creating a PrivateObject. Couldn't find a way to find if the right `HandleXYZ` was called.
3. Mocks/ Moqs- Can't Moq a private function...

How do I test if the right `UpsertXYZ` was invoked given the messageType?

Comment: Could you mock the data access layer? And check that the right function gets called that way? e.g. using NSubstitute (sorry the one I know atm) you can check if the function gets called, i.e. _dataAccessMock.UpsertFastAsync(Args.Any<>).ReceivedCalls(). etc etc. It is not really some much of a unit test anymore, but could still achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not mock a private function, but as @Heinrich said you could mock the data access layer and check that the right function is called via MOQ's verify function